# Inserting Select from HTML to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

so i have this table in my html

```
<form method = "POST" action="admin_event.php">
<table class = "table" id="dynamic_admin_add_price">
                                                        <thead>
                                                        <th>Deadline </th>
                                                        <th>Register Date</th>
                                                        <th>Price</th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        <th></th>
                                                        </thead>

                                                        <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <select name="admin_add_deadline[]" class="form-control">
                                                                    <option value="early_bird">Early Bird</option>
                                                                    <option value="middle">Middle</option>
                                                                    <option value="normal">Normal</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td><input type="text" name="admin_add_register_date[]" class="form-control registerDate" required></td>
                                                            <td><label>Rp.</label></td>
                                                            <td><input type="number" name="admin_add_price[]" class="form-control" value=""  required></td>
                                                            <td><button type="submit" name="button_add_price" id="price" class="btn btn-success">Add more deadlines</button></td>
                                                            <!--<td><button type="button" name=button_remove_event_time id="remove_event-time" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Remove</button></td>-->
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="admin_add_event_datas">Save</button>
</form>
```

And i have created the javascript so that the user can add as many rows as they want

```
    $('#add_price').click(function(){
    j++;
    $('#dynamic_admin_add_price').append(
        '<tr id="row2'+j+'">' +
        '<td><select name="admin_add_deadline[]" class="form-control"><option value="early_bird">Early Bird</option><option value="middle">Middle</option><option value="normal">Normal</option></select></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="admin_add_register_date[]" class="form-control registerDate" required></td>' +
        '<td><label>Rp.</label></td>' +
        '<td><input type="number" name="admin_add_price[]" class="form-control" value="" required></td>' +
        '<td><button type="submit" name="button_remove_event_time" id="'+j+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove2" required>Remove</button></td>' +
        '</tr>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove2', function(){
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row2'+button_id+'').remove();
});
```

The adding rows work fine and the rest of the data can be inputted into the mysql, EXCEPT for the select fields,where it returns incorrectly and doesn't get any input at all from the non-static rows.

What i want to do is that if the user chose early bird, it gave the number 1 in the php, 2 for the middle option, and 3 for the normal ones, as it matches the id_deadline in another table that is used as the foreign key in the table i want to insert the data to. This is the snippet of the php script(i only put the one for the deadline):

```
if(isset($_POST['admin_add_deadline'])){
$deadline = $_POST['admin_add_deadline'];

$one = 1;
$two = 2;
$three = 3;
if($deadline == 'early_bird'){

        $deadline = $one;
}

if($deadline == 'middle'){
        $deadline = $two;
}

else{
$deadline = $three
}


}
```

and this is the foreach to insert the data

```
    foreach ($register_date as $key => $value) {

    $post_register_date = $db->real_escape_string($value);

    $post_insert_price = $db->real_escape_string($register_price[$key]);

    $post_deadline = $deadline[$key];

    $query = "INSERT INTO register_time(id_event, id_deadline, register_date, price, created_at, status)
                          VALUES('$row_id_event','$post_deadline', '$post_register_date', '$post_insert_price', '$time', '$status')";

    if(mysqli_query($db, $query)){
        $succ = "New record created successfully";
    }

    else{
        echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db);
    }

}
```

Again, the problem is that if i have 3 rows generated and i clicked the submit button, the inserted value for the id_deadline column in the table will always be 3 for the first row, and the other 2 rows will return an error as the value is '' for the id_deadline in the insert query

Can you guys help me with this problem?Thank you, i hope my question is clear enough.

EDIT: Fixing the typos

Comment: Using this form field naming “snytax”, `$_POST['admin_add_deadline']` would be an array. Why are you trying to compare an array to string values? That makes no sense.

Comment: I follow the one in here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262434/how-to-get-value-of-selected-option-from-a-html-forms-dropdown-list-into-mysql

Comment: Over there, the field names do not contain `[]`, so this is a completely different situation. You have an array, so you need to loop over it and look at the individual items inside it. If you are ever unclear what data structure you are getting from your form, then use `var_dump($_POST);` to find out.

Comment: Ah, that's because there can be another rows that can be generated by button click, and the generated rows also contain the select field

Comment: Got it working now, just move the ifs and elses from the deadline into the foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now, just moved the ifs and elses from the deadline to the foreach

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in your code

1. Missing a double quotation mark in HTML action

   ```
   <form method = "POST" action="admin_event.php">
   ```
2. In your HTML

   ```
   $('#add_price').click(function(){
   ```

   doesn't exist in HTML, change for this:

   ```
    <td><a  id="add_price" id="price" class="btn btn-success">Add more deadlines</a></td>
   ```
3. In your jQuery, define `var j`:

   ```
   var j = 0;
   ```

In your PHP put this in to view the data:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    die;
}
```

My code works:
[image: form]

```
array(4) {
  ["admin_add_deadline"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "early_bird"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "middle"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "normal"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "middle"
  }
  ["admin_add_register_date"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "one"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "two"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "three"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "four"
  }
  ["admin_add_price"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  ["admin_add_event_datas"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an aswers.

Comment: Ah no, that was a typo in my part when copying the code into stackoverflow, since i have to change some of the variable names into english since it would probably more familiar to you guys.

It reached the controller yes, the data can be inserted, but only for the static row and the value is always 3 for the id_deadline and it doesn't get anything for the dynamic rows

Comment: Oh ok, I am sorry if my english make my explanation confusing haha

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i got it working now, just moved the ifs in the deadline inside the foreach.

Comment: please, put here the output of `var_dump($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell at this moment in third snippet you overriding `$deadline` variable with number, then you are using it in 4-th snippet as an array.

Your snippets are too sparse too say anything more, sorry...

Comment: It's ok, i misplaced the ifs and elses, got it working now. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: No worries :) Take care!